# PHP: parsed_str help please

Tags: php, string

This snippet works fine:

```
$url="Http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upenR6n7xWY&feature=BFa&list=PL88ACC6CB00DC2B44&index=4";

$parsed_url=parse_url($url);

echo "<br><br><pre>";
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo "</pre>";
echo $parsed_url['query'];
```

But when I add the below:

```
echo "<br><br><pre>";
$parsed_str=parse_str($parsed_url['query']);
print_r($parsed_str);
echo "</pre>";
```

Nothing happens. I suspect `parse_str()` isn't working as it should. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse_str() doesn't return anything. It populates variables.

For example, if you have a query string of $query = "param=1&test=2"

after 
parse_str($query);

you can check var_dump($param) and var_dump($test) - those two variables would be created for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the result of [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) in an array, pass the array as the second argument:

```
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);

var_dump($parsed_str);
```

I'm going to assume that the user inputs the URL. If so, **do not use `parse_str` without a second argument**!. Doing so would result in a security risk where the user can overwrite arbitrary variables with the value of their choice.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, parse_str converts

```
v=upenR6n7xWY&feature=BFa&list=PL88ACC6CB00DC2B44&index=4
```

To

```
$v = "upenR6n7xWY"
$feature = "BFa"
$list = "PL88ACC6CB00DC2B44"
$index = 4
```